# Need a regex to get string separated by underscore

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Need a regex to get string separated by underscore

I have string `one_two_three_four`

I need a regex to get only the second string `two` from the above string

MORE INFO ADDED:

I wanted this regex because I have a rdbms table where in a column will be having data in the format 'one_two_three_four', I just wanted to get 'two' from column when i fetch. Using below query. Instead me fetching the data and splitting data in java again.

```
select distinct(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, 'regex'))  
from table_name
```

Comment: Just split it by `_` and get the second element... a Regex here makes no sense

Comment: what language you are using?

Comment: You want something like this? `^([^_]*_){1}([^_])`

Comment: Ah, the plot thickens. You should also tag the database type. Because that kind of database function isn't standard sql, and has it's own regex flavor.

Comment: Its Oracle rdbms db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle you can indeed use [regexp_substr](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php).
Or the normal substr in combination with instr to get the positions of the underscores.

For example:

```
select 
 -- getting the 2nd match with non-underscore characters
 regexp_substr(val, '[^_]+', 1, 2) as method1,

 -- getting the (capture group)
 regexp_substr(val, '^.*?_(.*?)_', 1, 1, null, 1) as method2,

 -- substring on the positions of the underscores
 substr(val,instr(val,'_')+1,instr(val,'_',1,2)-instr(val,'_')-1) as method3

from (
    select 'one_two_three_four' as val from dual
) q
```

And in a programming language like Java?
Why regex when you can split?

```
String str = "one_two_three_four";
```

Split the string into an array and take element 1

```
String[] strArray = str.split("_");
String secondSplit = strArray[1];
```

Or in one shot:

```
String secondSplit = str.split("_")[1];
```

Btw, split also takes regular expressions.
So this works just as well:

```
String secondSplit = str.split("[_]")[1];
```

Comment: Why answer an off-topic question if it is going to be removed any time soon?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because I thought it would help him. And looking at the user's profile there was a fair chance that he's looking for a solution in Java.

Comment: I used to behave the same when I had less than 45K rep... It is painful to see when your reputation drops 30, 40, 75 points just because your upvoted/accepted answers get deleted with a poorly asked question.

Comment: I just added more info and history why needed the regex.

Comment: @GouthamNithyananda  Added an Oracle solution to the answer.

Comment: @LukStorms It worked like a charm! Thanks!!